# Returns as "Memes per second: 0 " When it should be 2

Tags: javascript, var

The following prints “Memes per second: 0 ” When it should be 2.

```js
document.getElementById('mps').innerHTML = "Memes per second: " + ((p + d + s + sk) * multiplier) + " ";

var multiplier = 1;
var memeCount = 0;
var pepe = 1;
var datboi = 0;
var sanic = 0;
var skeleton = 0;
var p = pepe * 2
var d = datboi * 10
var s = sanic * 50
var sk = skeleton * 300
```

```html
<div id="mps"></div>
```

Comment: It works! Post more code.

Comment: You need to define your variables before you use them. Move the first line to the bottom.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey The order was right because otherwise it'll print `undefined` instead of `0`

Comment: Oh, well I was kinda dumb there. Thanks guys.

Comment: Try computing the value separately and storing it in a variable. My next guess is that it had something to do with string and number concatenation instead of addition.

Comment: Well, it still not working. I could post the whole code for you to look at.

Comment: It doesn't return 0, it returns NaN as expected since all the variables have a value of *undefined*. You are using the variables before they are assigned values, move the first line to the end.